Exception when importing freeze in Python 3.13
I created a virtual env with;
conda create --name base_313 python=3.13 -y
conda activate base_313
code .

Then ran this code;
from types import freeze

class k:
    AGE = 42
    NAME = "Zoubida"

freeze(k)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(k.AGE)  # 42

    try:
        k.AGE = 84  
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)  

I got the exception below;
```powershell

Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name 'freeze' from 'types' (c:\Users\phili\anaconda3\envs\base_313\Lib\types.py)
File "C:\Users\phili\OneDrive\Documents\Tmp\const\main.py", line 24, in 
from types import freeze
ImportError: cannot import name 'freeze' from 'types' (c:\Users\phili\anaconda3\envs\base_313\Lib\types.py)

```powershell
conda --version   
conda 24.5.0


i don't see this types.freeze mentioned anywhere, i don't think it exists in python, where did you get this code from ? which source says that this code should work ?

For example you can read : https://medium.com/@pythonshield/python-3-13-an-overview-of-the-latest-features-enhancements-and-best-practices-5ab5a2f33960
I'll try to find formal documentation and come back here.

Most of that site content is AI generated, and as far as i can tell nothing in this article is true
